# Transfer files of different extensions from one server to another on linux?

Tags: unix, ssh, sftp, scp

Below are the files in my InputLocation in local server

```
-rw-r----- 1 root root 0 Sep 25 15:03 one.xml
-rw-r----- 1 root root 0 Sep 25 15:03 two.xml
-rw-r----- 1 root root 0 Sep 25 15:03 data.csv
-rw-r----- 1 root root 0 Sep 25 15:03 free.png
-rw-r----- 1 root root 0 Sep 25 15:04 loaded.jpeg
```

I am able to transfer files using the below command

```
scp ${InputPath}/*.{jpeg,xml} ${user}@${HostName}:$OutputPath
```

But i am trying to put the extns in a variable as below

```
FilesExtnsToBeTransfered=jpeg,xml
scp ${InputLocation}/*.{$FilesExtnsToBeTransfered} ${user}@${HostName}:$OutputPath
```

But i am getting the below exception though the files are available

```
InputLocation/*.{jpeg,xml}: No such file or directory
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saying:

```
FilesExtnsToBeTransfered=jpeg,xml
echo {$FilesExtnsToBeTransfered}
```

would result in `{jpeg,xml}` (*brace expansion would not be performed*).

You have two options:

1. (Ugly, not recommended): Use `eval`.

   `eval scp ${InputLocation}/*.{$FilesExtnsToBeTransfered} ${user}@${HostName}:$OutputPath`
2. Put the desired file extensions in an array:

> ```
> EXTNS=( jpeg xml )
> for i in "${EXTNS[@]}"; do
>   scp ${InputLocation}/*.$i ${user}@${HostName}:$OutputPath
> done
> ```